# How to submit a bug/patch for joint_state_publisher

Tags: joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I have a found a bug within the joint_state_publisher.  I would like to submit a bug/patch but I cannot find the proper bug trac.

The package wiki doesn't have a link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_state_publisher

The stack wiki has a link, but it is broken: http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_model_visualization

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33145/how-to-submit-a-bug/patch-for-joint_state_publisher/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/Trac) should be the right link.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0